# What is the algorithm for grouping means in a multiple comparisons LSD test?

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, fishers-lsd

Starting from the means of 10 treatments where the Fisher LSD interval is 2.1, how do you "manually" determine the number of homogeneous groups (a, b, c, d ...) and which mean belongs to which one?

```r
treatments = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 
               "eight", "nine", "ten")
means = c(6.4, 7.6, 8.7, 8.9, 9.1, 9.4, 9.6, 9.8, 9.9, 11.0)
LSD = 2.1
```

The pairwise comparison is easy to understand, however, the grouping of multiple means at the same time is complex.

I'm looking for an algorithm in R to understand the grouping process of the significantly different means.

Comment: With 10 treatments you probably shouldn't be using Fisher's LSD. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/106367/28500), for example.